# How to convert datetimefield to string in Django values_list() function?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime, django-models

I have a model which contains a `datetime` field.
I need to write the rows from that model table to excel sheet.

As the model field is `datetime` field, when writing to the excel, it's writing a number like **45976** etc for dates instead of **2020-04-01** as string.

I'm getting values of rows using `queryset.values_list(*fields_to_fetch)` This `fields_to_fetch` contains the datetimefield I'm looking for. When I print the type, it is saying `DateTimeField` in the console.

Is there any way to get the `datetimefield` as string type?

I was able to convert each item in the `values_list()` to list and then the `datetimefield` into string and append it to a new list and write to excel.

I'm looking for a way to avoid all this.

Answer (score 3):

Use [**`Cast(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) database function,

```
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
from django.db.models import CharField

cast_expr = Cast('date_time_field', output_field=CharField())
data = ModelKlass.objects.annotate(dt_as_str=cast_expr).values_list('dt_as_str')
```

Comment: In the annotate, I want to assign the cast_expression to same field name in my model and it's raising conflict for that. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: you can't do that

Comment: Or Is there any way to get the elements as `list` instead of `tuple` in `values_list()`?

Comment: I don;t understand that, can you explain bit more?

Comment: When I use `values_list()`, each element in that list is of type `tuple`. Can I get each element as `list` instead of `tuple`. Is there any parameter that I can pass to `values_list()`?

Comment: use **`flat=True`** as **`.values_list('dt_as_str', flat=True)`**

Comment: Yes. When I use `flat=True`, it's returning each element as `tuple` type. Not as `list`. I'm getting `[ ( ), ( ), ( ) ]`. I'm looking for `[ [ ], [ ], [ ] ]`.

Comment: Oh.. that's too not possible out of the box.